# How do I make a UIImageView darker when highlighted (tapped)?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIImageView that shows a picture. When tapped and held, I'd like it to darken as long as the user has their finger over the imageview. Basically, I want it to act like a UIButton.

I currently have it do this with a UIGestureRecognizer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self
                                         action:@selector(pictureViewTapped)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self.pictureImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [self.pictureImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

and in my `pictureViewTapped`, I have this (for now):

```
- (void)pictureViewTapped {
    NSLog(@"Picture view was tapped!");
}
```

How do I make the UIImageView darker? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to behave like a button, why don't you use a button ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Easiest way is to use layers in the QuartzCore framework:

add: QuartzCore.framework to project in your project settings
add to .h file: #import

create gesture for long press instead of tap as that behaviors as you described:

```
 self.longTap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(darkenImage)];
    [self.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:self.longTap];
```

method called when gesture active:

```
-(void)darkenImage {
    switch (self.longTap.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: // object pressed
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            [self.imageView.layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
            [self.imageView.layer setOpacity:0.9];
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: // object released
            [self.imageView.layer setOpacity:1.0];
            break;
        default: // unknown tap
            NSLog(@"%i", self.longTap.state);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `[self.imageView.layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
            [self.imageView.layer setOpacity:0.9];`


Is the intention that the background will show through when you set the whole imageViews opacity to 0.9? Should the background not be affected by the opacity change? Anyhow, this doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: @Toydor I agree, I recommend future readers try utilizing the `.tintColor` property instead.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, background will show through when set ImageView's layer opacity to 0.9.

I use solution that use new layer.

```
let coverLayer = CALayer()
coverLayer.frame = imageView.bounds;
coverLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
coverLayer.opacity = 0.0
imageView.layer.addSublayer(coverLayer)

// when tapped
coverLayer.opacity = 0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift-Solution:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewExport: UIImageView!
var tapGestureExport = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageViewExport.userInteractionEnabled = true

        tapGestureExport = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapGestureExportAction:")
        imageViewExport.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureExport)
    }

    func tapGestureExportAction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        switch(tapGestureExport.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began,
                UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
            imageViewExport.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            imageViewExport.layer.opacity = 0.9

        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:        // released
            imageViewExport.layer.opacity = 1.0

            default: break // unknown tap 
            }
}
```